# Multi Downloading With javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I created a table filled with file names in a directory. Now i want to download this files from uploaded directory.  I m getting multiple file names then parsing them to send them one by one.I menaged this with this code but it only downloads last file.

```
    while (dowloadParts[i] != "")
    {
    window.location = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Uploads/" + dowloadParts[i];
    }
```

What should i do to menage multiple file download.

Comment: Try this link http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with creating iframe for every single download file request. here is my code;

```
     function downloadFile(filesForDownload) {
        i = 0;
        var downloadParts = filesForDownload.split(';');

        while (downloadParts[i] != "") {

            downloadURL("http://" + window.location.host + "/Uploads/" + downloadParts[i]);
            i++;
        } 
    }
    var count = 0;


     var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url) {

        var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.src = url;
    }
```